# Set jquery selector dynamically based on HTML form ID value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have several forms on one page that differ based on the forms' IDs. The ID's differ by an appended _0, _1, _2 etc (an index value created by a rails each do loop).

I'm trying to validate these forms, however to keep my code DRY, I'd like the form selector to be dynamic. I need to somehow grab the form's ID value ("_0") and add it to the jQuery selector.

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7w6huhp9/3/) gives an exmaple of how I'm tackling the problem now.
The code inside of the validation() block is the same between the jQuery functions. I need to set the selector variable to something like this:

```
$("new_loan_question_answer_"+i)
```

I'm not sure how to pass the _0 or _1 form the HTML form to the jQuery function.

**form html**

```
<div class="form">
    <p>Question #1 text</p>
    <form id="question_response_0">
        <input type="text" name="response"></input>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <p>Question #2 text</p>
    <form id="question_response_1">
        <input type="text" name="response"></input>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#question_response_0").validate({
        rules: {
            "response": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "response": {
                required: 'This field is required'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#question_response_1").validate({
        rules: {
            "response": {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "response": {
                required: 'This field is required'
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element.parent());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You'd have better to use a class or any transversal selector to bind event, e.g: `$('.form form').validate(...);`

Comment: Someone needs to make one of those Batman-slapping-Robin images where Robin is asking "How can I use JQuery to ID-select--" and Batman interrupts with "STOP OVERUSING IDS!"
Only use an ID if there's only going to be one thing of that type in the whole wide world.

Comment: are all your rules going to be the same for each form? if so you can use the id starts with selector: `jQuery("form[id^='question_response']" )` but as others have said, I would add a class

Comment: @Katana314 I've tried using classes in this situation. It seems like jQuery validation() needs the ID of each individual form to know which form to append the error HTML code to. See updated fiddle using classes as selector: http://jsfiddle.net/7w6huhp9/4/

Comment: @Questifier, not if you use the each loop: http://jsfiddle.net/7w6huhp9/5/ (you can swap in a class for the selector I have used)

Comment: @Questifer Darn; that's pretty confusing if JQuery briefly gives up on its rules of "operate on multiple elements". Pete is right that it can still work via classes, but you need to keep track of the forms via proper variable references inside functions, rather than ID selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with incremental `id` attributes. It becomes a pain to maintain and leads to issues keeping code DRY. This kind of thing is *exactly* what classes were invented for:

```
<div class="form">
    <p>Question #1 text</p>
    <form class="question_response"> <!-- < use a common class on the form -->
        <input type="text" name="response"></input>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="form">
    <p>Question #2 text</p>
    <form class="question_response"> <!-- < use a common class on the form -->
        <input type="text" name="response"></input>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Now you only need to attach validate to the `.question_response` class. Unfortunately it seems that the error highlighting (and possibly other features) is bugged in the validate plugin when instantiating on a selector that contains multiple form elements, so you need to loop through each form in turn:

```
$(function () {
    $('.question_response').each(function() {
        $(this).validate({
            rules: {
                "response": {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                "response": {
                    required: 'This field is required'
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element.parent());
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7w6huhp9/6/)

Comment: Using classes here doesn't seem to work for me. jQuery validation() seems to append the error message to the first input if you're using classes. See: http://jsfiddle.net/7w6huhp9/4/

Comment: @Questifier that's very disappointing. I think I may even raise that as a bug in validate.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://api.jquery.com/submit/ for example.

If you use an event handler to call a function, then the event may contain the information you need (ID of submitted form).

Information regarding the event object is available here: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 0):

Could use the classes shown already in your markup, or add a class to form tags:

```
$('div.form form').validate({/* options*/}) ;
```

This will include all forms that match the selector and each will have it's own validation instance